# Check if my pages are cached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-appcache, cache-manifest, manifest.cache

I have a page that links to a manifest file. The manifest file has many urls in it. Usually it takes a few minutes to load everything.

How can I check if my pages have finished caching so I can tell the user "Your files are cached. It is safe to go offline now"?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/#toc-updating-cache

Answer (score 0):

The `applicationCache` global fires several events you can check for to handle this. There are a few cases that need to be considered.

The *very first* time the manifest is downloaded by a user's browser (or the first time they revisit the site after they delete the appcache record), the `applicationCache` will fire a `cached` event once all resources have been downloaded.

If the user has visited the site before, and the browser determines that the manifest hasn't changed since their last visit, the `applicationCache` will fire a `noupdate` event, indicating that the user is ready to go offline.

If, on the other hand, the manifest file has changed, then it will re-download all of the files in the manifest. Once done, it will trigger a `updateready` event. However:

> *The new version is not yet in use*. To “hot-swap” to the new version without forcing the user to reload the page, you can manually call the window.applicationCache.swapCache() function.

In this case, once the `updateready` event is fired and (optionally) `application.swapCache()` is called, the user is ready to go offline.

[source](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html)